# Button inside tableViewCell not calling IBAction

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have created both `UICollectionView` and `UITableView` on my `View`

Inside `tableViewCell`'s `ViewController`, there is an action listener :

.h:

```
- (IBAction)addItem:(id)sender
```

.m:

```
- (IBAction)addItem:(id)sender {
    UIButton * button  = ( UIButton * )sender;
    NSLog(@"add item button clicked");
}
```

I wanted to execute this function by clicking both the `Cell` in my `UICollectionView` and a `UIButton` inside each `tableViewCell`

the following codes work perfectly for clicking my `UICollectionView`'s cell

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    Item * selectedItem = [collectionDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //get item object from my collectionView's data array

    if ([tableDataArray containsObject:selectedItem]){
        //check if my tableView's data array having the same object

            NSUInteger itemIndex = [tableDataArray indexOfObject:selectedItem];
            NSIndexPath * indexpathOfTable = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:itemIndex inSection:0];
            //get indexPath of the cell containing the item object

            myTableCell * tableCell = (myTableCell*)[myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexpathOfTable];

            [myTableCell addItem:self];
            //executing action listener here

    }else{

        [tableDataArray addObject: selectedItem];

    }

    [myTableView reloadData];

}
```

`didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is working fine as well

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSLog(@"cell clicked");
}
```

However, it will no longer execute the `addItem` function for the `UIButton` I added inside my `UITableView` no matter I add selector for the button when generating `tableViewCell` or I create `UIButton` with linked `IBAction` for my `tableViewCell` inside `Interface Builder`
I've implemented both `UITableViewDelegate`and `UICollectionViewDelegate`

I think it never detect my clicking gesture for my `UITableView` but detect the one for `UICollectionView`

Is there anyone help me on this? thanks a lot

Comment: did you linked your IBAction with your button in tableviewcell..?

Comment: @RamaniAshish Definitely linked, I tried using selector as well